# file not found in current directory

Tags: powershell

I have the following script:

```
function Export-sql-toExcel {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [string]$scriptFile,
        [string]$excelFile,
        [string]$serverInstance,
        [string]$database,
        [string]$userName,
        [string]$password
    )
    $tokens = ( [system.io.file]::ReadAllText( $scriptFile ) -split '(?:\bGO\b)' )
    foreach ($token in $tokens) {
        $token = $token.Trim()
        if ($token -ne "") {
            $lines = $token -split '\n'
            $title = $lines[0]
            if ($title.StartsWith("--")) {
                $title = $title.Substring(2)
                $title
            }
            Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database $database -Username $userName -Password $password -Query $token  |
            Export-Excel -Path $excelFile -WorkSheetname $title -FreezeTopRow -ExcludeProperty RowError,RowState,Table,ItemArray,HasErrors
        }
    }

}
```

I have installed this function as a module. When I invoke the command from, for example, desktop folder, like this:

```
PS D:\Usuarios\mnieto\Desktop> Export-sql-toExcel -scriptFile .\EXPORT.txt -excelFile Excel.xlsx
```

I get the following error (the export.txt file is in the desktop folder):

```
Exception calling "ReadAllText" with "1" argument(s): "Can't find the file 'D:\Usuarios\<MyUserName>\EXPORT.txt'."
```

**EDITED**

if I debug and try [system.environment]::CurrentDirectory, it returns 
`'D:\Usuarios\<MyUserName>`
That is because my script fails. NET functions and powershell don't share the 'current directory'

Any other way to get the content and parse the $scriptFile file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution changing the NET call by a powershell command at this line

```
$content = Get-Content $scriptFile -Raw
$tokens = ( $content -split '(?:\bGO\b)' )
```

the trick was in the -Raw parameter, so the file is read as a single string

Answer (score 1):

To my experience .dot NET functions don't like relative path's.

I'd use

```
$scriptfile = (Get-Item $Scriptfile).FullName
```

to resolve to a full path in the function just ahead :

```
$tokens = ( [system.io.file]::ReadAllText( $scriptFile ) -split '(?:\bGO\b)' )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, it was resolved when i added a dot "." to call the csv

> $path2 = $path + ".\file.csv"

Or check for spaces at the $excelFile variable.

Comment: But what happen if I pass an absolute path in the call: `Export-sql-toExcel -scriptFile c:\EXPORT.txt `. I can't use dot to prepend the file name